# Send inline images using send-mailmessage

Tags: html, powershell, sendmail

I am trying to send an html formatted email with inline images from the command line using send-mailmessage. I have looked everywhere and wasn't able to find the solution. I am able to get the email to send but the recipient doesn't receive the images. Here is my code:

```
$smtp = "smtp.server.com" 
$to = "recp@example.com" 
$from = "from@example.com" 
$subject = "This is a subject"
$body = (-join(Get-content \email.html))

send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from  -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml  -Body $body
```

If there is a problem in the code or if there is a different solution please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet. To include inline image in message you have to write your own function using .NET's [Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class.

Alternatively, you can just grab David Wyatt's [Send-MailMessage](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d) function, which already has all you need:

> The `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet exposes most of the basic functionality
>   for sending email, but you don't get a lot of control over things like
>   attachments or alternate views.  Someone on the TechNet forums was
>   asking how to embed images into an HTML mail message, and I decided to
>   write a version of `Send-MailMessage` that supports this.  I started
>   with a proxy function for the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet, so all of the
>   parameters and usage should be intact.  The main difference is that I
>   added an `-InlineAttachments` argument, which accepts a hashtable of
>   pairs in the format `'ContentId'='FilePath'`.  You can then embed the
>   resources into an HTML body by using URLs of the format
>   `cid:ContentId`.