# Embed images in email and send via Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I am editing one of my old scripts to send an email to a user with images embedded into the text. I am trying to use the Send-MailMessage function to send the email as opposed to the older method of $smtp.send($msg). However, when trying to update the script, the images are no longer being embedded.

I know how to attach them to the email as actual attachments, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong to have them show as actual embedded images.

NOTE: for brevity, I removed some of the full email since it is large and as long as I can get an image or two working, it will all work.

```
# force powershell to run as an x86 process
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
    if ($env:Processor_Architecture -ne "x86") {
        &"$env:windir\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file $myinvocation.Mycommand.path
        exit
    }

# initialize the script
    if ($startupvariables) { try {Remove-Variable -Name startupvariables  -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } catch { } }
    New-Variable -force -name startupVariables -value ( Get-Variable | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } )
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
    $Separator = ".", "@"

# advise what the script does
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
    $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OKCancel
    $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
    $MessageTitle = "Shared Drive Access Assistance"
    $MessageBody = "This script asks the user to provide more information regarding a network drive that they would like access to.`n`nTo use it, enter the below information:`n`n`n`tTicket Number`n`n`tUser's Email Address`n`n`tRequestor's Email Address`n`n`nIf this is the script you want to use, click OK.`nIf not, click Cancel."
    $Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)

    if ($Result -eq "Cancel")
    {
    Exit-PSSession
    }
    else
    {

# get the ticket number
    $Ticket = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the SCTask ticket number" , "Ticket Number")

# get the user id via the email address
    $UserID = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the user's email address" , "User Email Address")
    $User = $UserID.split($Separator)
    $Firstname = $User[0].substring(0,1).toupper()+$User[0].substring(1).tolower()
    $Lastname = $User[1].substring(0,1).toupper()+$User[1].substring(1).tolower()
    $User = $Firstname, $Lastname

# get local username
    $Username = [System.Environment]::UserName

# create email
    $subject = "Ticket $Ticket on Hold for User Response - Shared Drive Access for $User - Awaiting Additional Information"
    $body = @"
    <html>
    <body style="font-family:calibri"> 
    To $Requestor, $User,<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    In order to proceed with your request for shared drive access, we require the server name and full path to the folder you need access to. If you do not already know this information, you will need to provide these instructions to someone that already has access to the folder that you need access to.<br>
    <br>
    1)  Click the Start menu<br>
    <br>
    <img src="cid:image1.png"><br>
    <img src="cid:image2.png"><br>
    <img src="cid:image3.png"><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    2)  Navigate to "Computer"<br>
    <br>
    <img src="cid:image4.png"><br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    If you have any questions or need assistance with this process, please contact the Service Desk via one of the methods listed below. 
    <br>
    <br>
    Thank You,<br>
    <br>
    IT Service Desk<br>

    </body>
    </html>
"@

    $att1 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive1.png")
    $att2 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive2.png")
    $att3 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive3.png")
    $att4 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive4.png")
    $att1.ContentId = "image1.png"
    $att2.ContentId = "image2.png"
    $att3.ContentId = "image3.png"
    $att4.ContentId = "image4.png"
#    $msg.Attachments.Add($att1)
#    $msg.Attachments.Add($att2)
#    $msg.Attachments.Add($att3)
#    $msg.Attachments.Add($att4)

# create confirmation message
    $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
    $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
    $MessageTitle = "Shared Drive Access Assistance"
    $MessageBody = "The information you have entered is show below:`n`n`nTicket Number: $Ticket`n`nUser's Email Address: $UserID`n`nRequstor's Email Address: $RequestorID`n`n`nIf you would like to send the email, click Yes.`nOtherwise, click No."
    $Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
    if ($Result -eq "No")
    {
    Exit-PSSession
    }
    else

# send email
    {
    Send-MailMessage -To "<$UserID>" -bcc "<$Username@dana.com>" -from "<itservicedesk@x.com>" -Subject $global:subject -SmtpServer "mailrelay.x.com" -BodyAsHtml -body $global:body
    }
    }

Function Clean-Memory {
    Get-Variable |
        Where-Object { $startupVariables -notcontains $_.Name } |
            ForEach-Object {
            try { Remove-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Force -Scope "global" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
                catch { }
 }
 }
```

Comment: I had the same problem as you and i end up using the Send-InlineMailMessage module https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d also take a look at this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041698/send-inline-images-using-send-mailmessage

Comment: Oh wow, okay.  I will have to figure out how to get that to work.  None of my other scripts have images embedded, so I can use Send-MailMessage without issue

Comment: I am writing a solution

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So the real question is how to embed a image into the HTML document from a attachment

CID aka Content ID will allow you to attach a image and then use that attached image in the document. Avoid using spaces in the Content ID name.

```
Send-MailMessage -To "Test@Test.com" -from "Test2@Test.com" -SmtpServer SMTP.TEST.NET -Subject "Hello" -BodyAsHtml -Body "<img src='cid:Test.png'>" -Port 25 -Attachments "C:\Users\Test\Test.png"
```

You are using

```
$att1 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive1.png")
$att2 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive2.png")
$att3 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive3.png")
$att4 = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ("T:\PS Scripts\Images\shareddrive4.png")
$att1.ContentId = "image1.png"
$att2.ContentId = "image2.png"
$att3.ContentId = "image3.png"
$att4.ContentId = "image4.png"
```

but when you send the mail you are not attaching those attachments

```
Send-MailMessage -To "<$UserID>" -bcc "<$Username@dana.com>" -from "<itservicedesk@x.com>" -Subject $global:subject -SmtpServer "mailrelay.x.com" -BodyAsHtml -body $global:body
```

You could stop using the `Net.Mail.Attachment` and instead do something like

```
$Body = @"
    <html>
        <body style="font-family:calibri"> 
            <b>This is image 1</b>
            <img src='cid:TEST1.png'>
            <b>This is image 2</b>
            <img src='cid:Test2.png'>
        </body>
    </html>
"@

Send-MailMessage -To "Test@Test.com" `
    -from "Test2@Test.com" `
    -SmtpServer Test.smtp.com `
    -Subject "Hello" `
    -BodyAsHtml -body $body `
    -Attachments "C:\Test\TEST1.png", "C:\Test\TEST2.png"
```

Comment: What a simple and elegant solution!  Thanks for this :-)

Comment: Is it possible to add an image to the "body" part without attaching anything. Like the same as when you copy an image and paste it in the body part of your e-mail client....?

Comment: No The Image ether needs to be attached OR it needs to be accessible by the client. Like a reference of a image accessible on there network.

Comment: It's not working for me, I'm not getting the images...they get attached but don't show in the email...
https://s3.gifyu.com/images/imagesdontshow.png

Comment: @RicardoBohner You are not proving enough information to help you. I would need to see the script to determine what you are doing wrong

Comment: @ArcSet: It's the examle you posted after..."and instead do something like.."  Except, slightly addaped for my e-mail....

Comment: I like this, I think there should be an option to have a hidden kind of attachment when embedded but this is a deprecated commandlet now and we have to use something like .NET MailKit now.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the image into the HTML, therefore there are no extra files.
It is replacing

```
{img=file}
```

with data URL

```
{src="data:image/png;base64,[base64 encoded long string representing the image]}
```

There are many online converters that can convert your image file into the required code.

Just google for Image to Data URI converter.

Comment: Actually although this is fine for web browser rendering it seems most email clients will not display these images:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008440/embedded-images-not-showing-in-outlook-while-its-showing-in-browser

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example using MailKit.  I had do download the packages from https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKit and https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit and unpack with 7Zip as PowerShell was struggling to install from the CLI.  I got some ideas from here but wanted to add an example of an embedded image, https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-email.

You can do all sorts with MimeKit and MailKit including modern Auth which is great.  It's also supper fast and the Client and even a Connection can be used in a loop to send lots of messages.  There is probably an upper bound on how long to use a connection without refreshing?

```
$mailServer = "domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"

$SMTP = New-Object MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient

Add-Type -Path ".\mailkit.3.3.0\netstandard2.0\MailKit.dll"
Add-Type -Path ".\mimekit.3.3.0\netstandard2.0\MimeKit.dll"

$SMTP.Connect($mailServer, 25, [MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions]::StartTls, $False)

$Message  = New-Object MimeKit.MimeMessage
 
$message.From.Add("a.person@domain.com");
$message.To.Add("b.person@domain.com");
$message.Subject = "Some Subject";

$builder = [MimeKit.BodyBuilder]::new();

$image = $builder.LinkedResources.Add($path);
$image.ContentId=[MimeKit.Utils.MimeUtils]::GenerateMessageId();

$body = @"
 <html>
     <body style="font-family:calibri"> 
         <b>This is image 1</b>
         <img src="cid:$($image.ContentId)">
     </body>
 </html>
"@

$builder.HtmlBody = $body

#Now we just need to set the message body and we're done
$message.Body = $builder.ToMessageBody();
$SMTP.Send($Message)

$SMTP.Disconnect($true)
$SMTP.Dispose()
```