# Image not displayed in the mail using powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, email

I want to display a picture in the mail from a powershell code, below is the script used

```
$ImagePath="G:\DBScripts\BufferInfo_$(get-date -format `"yyyyMMdd_hhmmsstt`").png"
$BarChart.SaveImage($ImagePath,"png")
$recipient = "recipient@domain.com" 
$smtpserver = "smtpserver.com" 
$smtpport = "XX"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($ImagePath)
$attach.ContentType.MediaType = “image/png”
$msg.Attachments.Add($attach)
$msg.From = "ServerStats.com"
$msg.To.Add($recipient)
$msg.Subject = "DBStats" 
$msg.Body = "<img src='cid:($attach.ContentID)'>"
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

And the image is -width 1800 -height 500.

I was able to receive the mail with attachment, however image is not displayed and it shows a box with X sign.

[image: outlook mail screenshot]

any advise would be really helpful. Thanks.

i got this fixed, as below

```
$Body = @"
    <html>
        <body style="font-family:calibri"> 
            <b>BufferPool Usage</b>
            <img src='cid:$BufImageName'>
            <b>CacheStore Report-1</b>
            <img src='cid:$CSImageName'>
            <b>CacheStore Report-2</b>
            <img src='cid:$CS1ImageName'>
        </body>
    </html>
"@

Send-MailMessage -To $recipient `
    -from "FROM" `
    -SmtpServer $smtpserver `
    -Subject "MSSQL Stats Report" `
    -BodyAsHtml -body $body `
    -Attachments $BufImagePath,$CSImagePath,$CS1ImagePath
```

Comment: Have you tried to Write-Host the $attach.ContentID? You might need to apply a string value to it.

Comment: There is a much simpler approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837468/embed-images-in-email-and-send-via-powershell

Comment: @Palle Due ....Thanks. However, i still see the same issue. Image comes as attachment but it will not be displayed in the mail.

Comment: @PalleDue i still see same issue

Comment: Have you tried making the `Body` valid html? As it is now it's only an img tag.

Comment: Thanks... it worked....